# Timeline of the frequency of Bedikos

Tags: history, niddah, inspection

The Talmud states (Mishna, top of [Niddah 13a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=13&format=pdf)):

> כל היד המרבה לבדוק בנשים משובחת
>
> The more *bedikos* (checks for menstruation) that a woman does, the better

This is brought in the [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 184:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5475).

Sometime between then and now, it became prevalent (in my experience with anyone I have spoken to about the matter) for those teaching the laws of family purity to instruct that women should *not* do any additional checks.  One reason given is that since our bedikos today, due to our uncertainty and lack of proficiency, only produce doubtful or questionable results, they do not fulfill this praiseworthy practice (Igros Moshe Y.D. 4, pg. 201).  Another reason is that women today are more sensitive, and doing increased checks causes unnecessary bleeding, which is painful and causes more halachic problems (citation needed).

My question is, when did this begin to change, and when did it become prevalent?

(Bonus brownie points for sources to the second reason)

Comment: You can throw in the lenient approach to moch dachuk as well which based on your premise number two.

Comment: Note that according to Rambam bedika is kinuah, so it doesnt matter if women are sensitive, the practice does not hut.